# Realizar consulta SQL desde Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

Buenas,

Tengo entendido que no se puede realizar una consulta SQL desde Javascript, pero no sé si la información que he encontrado a través de Google puede estar obsoleta o no. El caso es que tengo unos elementos  que al pulsarlos se ejecuta un pequeño script:

```
var heart = 0;
$('#heart').click(function(){
    console.log(heart);

    if (heart == 0) {
        document.getElementById('heart').style.color = '#e74c3c ';
        document.getElementById('heart').style.background = 'transparent';
        heart = 1;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('heart').style.color = 'white';
        document.getElementById('heart').style.background = '#5dc21e';
        heart = 0;
    }
});
```

Lo que me gustaría es que no sólo me cambiase los estilos, también insertar en una tabla de la base de datos unos datos o quitarlos.

Con `onclick` entiendo que tampoco puedo hacer lo que quiero porque también me llevaría a un script.

No se me ocurre cómo solventar el problema.

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Comment: ¿ Te refieres a una base de datos *en local*, usado [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/IndexedDB-840092-dup/Usando_IndexedDB), o a actualizar datos en una BD externa, alojada en un servidor ?

Comment: @Trauma en un principio en local, pero antes o después va a acabar un servidor. Es para un foro, para que nos entendamos, ahora es simplemente para maquetar y crear las funcionalidades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En local no hay problema usando la API que te indiqué en el comentario (si el navegador lo soporta, claro).

En remoto ... no te queda mas remedio que usar código en el servidor: PHP, Nodejs, ... lo que prefieras. Y algo de Javascript en el cliente. Javascript, por si mismo, **no puede establecer conexiones con BBDD**; está limitado a peticiones HTTP, y, últimamente, a conexiones WebSockets.

El *truco* consiste en realizar llamadas AJAX al servidor WEB, y que este responda con los datos que quieras. Tanto en este sitio como por Internet hay bastante documentación sobre AJAX.

Si la versión final de tu código va a necesitar un servidor de BBDD externo, mi recomendación es que empieces usándolo **desde ya**. El código entre usar IndexedDB y realizar llamadas AJAX **no es directamente transportable**, y podrás aprovechar poco de uno para el otro (la comprobación de datos y poco mas). Además, las solicitudes AJAX, en el lado del servidor, te mostrarán algún que otro *inconveniente* adicional. Ya irás preguntando ;-)

Comment: No sé si he entendido bien. Uso PHP para realizar las consultas a base de datos, hasta ahora no he tenido problema (para hacer búsquedas por ejemplo), pero nunca he hecho un INSERT con PHP en un servidor, en local sin problemas.

No conozco AJAX, espero no estar complicando las cosas.

Comment: El *protocolo* para lo que quieres hacer es sencillo. Desde Javascript lanzas una consulta AJAX; dicha consulta es recibida por tu PHP, bién como $_GET[], bien como $_POST[] (tu escoges). La procesas en PHP, y respondes a la peticion (que tu iniciaste) con los datos necesarios. Busca por AJAX en Google, hay tropecientas páginas.

Comment: Las consultas AJAX **no son peticiones de páginas** desde el punto de vista del navegador. Para un posible usuario, todo lo anterior está *oculto*; no se entera del trasiego de información.

Comment: Gracias, creo que con la pregunta que he hecho no se puede profundizar más sin salirse de la pregunta en cuestión, así que acepto tu respuesta como la solución, y en el caso de tener dudas de cómo hacerlo abriré otra pregunta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @JetLagFox ciertamente, el tema por el que preguntas es *extenso* de mas; como te indiqué antes, en Internet hay mucha información sobre el mismo, con una gran parte en español.